# Specify multiple values for point tooltip using Chart.DataBindCrossTable()

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, charts

I'm using a Microsoft chart control and binding a `DataTable` to it using `Chart.DataBindCrossTable` One of the parameters is a string called `otherFields` and you can specify any property associated with a Point in that string:

```
chart.DataBindCrossTable(table.Rows, "COLUMN1", "COLUMN2", "COLUMN3", "Label=COLUMN4, LegendText=COLUMN1, ToolTip=COLUMN3");
```

I wan't to specify multiple columns in the ToolTip field, something like:

```
ToolTip=COLUMN3 = COLUMN4
```

so that the tool tip for each point would be "COLUMN3 = COLUMN4" where column3 and 4 would be filled in with whatever the values were in those columns/rows for that point.

But when I do this I get an error saying that there wasn't a column called "COLUMN3 = COLUMN4" in the datasource. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You could create another calculated column in your datatable to display what you want and bind to that.